# Does a Visual Studio debug build contain any personal information?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering about **privacy and personal information** that's contained in the debug files created by Visual Studio.

I have a project that I have compiled for both debug and release, and I have to zip basically the whole directory tree that contains the solution, the source, the pdbs, etc. and make it available.

I'm wondering **what type of information will be released** by doing this, other than source and binaries obviously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done correctly you will not release any personal information by doing this.

Things to watch out for:

- Sensitive information in paths. If you keep your source files in My Documents folder, your Windows user name will be leaked in .pdb files, as it embeds full source file paths. I recommend copying solution to directory c:\dev\project (or similar) and rebuilding there.
- Don't publish .suo, .user files, as these may contain sensitive information, and are generated by studio automatically for each user
- Look out for sensitive information that may be in app.config files

One more suggestion: don't publish any intermediate files (usually in obj directory). These will not help recipients in any way, but may contain personal information.

Comment: So far I'm excluding *.suo *.ilk *.user *.sdf. I'm not excluding *.obj files. Should I exclude them? Do they contain any useful information for the debugger? Also what about *.config files? Can I just exclude them entirely?

Comment: .obj files are not used by debugger. I think you should provide .config files as you use them, if they don't contain any sensitive information (use your own judgement on what should not be disclosed to those other parties). If .config files contain sensitive information, you should replace that information with dummy information when making your project available.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Thanks again