# Autogenerated sensitive data in Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio, security, github, open-source

Recently I was publishing my `Visual Studio` `Console application` project to `GitHub` and noticed that `.sln` file contains information about TFS Server (which I do not consider that sensitive though).

I would like to ask what shall I pay attention to when deploying such a project to open-source platform? To decrease any leak of sensitive info. Not talking about hard-coded connection strings, path or even passwords - but the auto generated code/data by `Visual Studio`.

I found that question [Does a Visual Studio debug build contain any personal information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435937/does-a-visual-studio-debug-build-contain-any-personal-information) summarizes basics of security for publishing projects by excluding `.suo` files.

What about `csproj.vspscc`, `.vssscc` or e.g. `AssemblyInfo.cs` can they contain any sensitive information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i saw before in other project , they ignore the .sln from committing in to the repository .
by the way i have an answer in mind , why would you want to publish a project on github when you have a TFS server for that ? 
in fact , have this check list in mind :

Put the following files in version control:

- dsw (VS6 workspace)
- dsp (VS6 project)
- *proj (VS Project files of various types)

of course your source files and other artifacts you create
Do not put the following files into version control:

- ncb (something to do with browsing or intellsense)
- sln (sensitive data)
- suo (user workspace settings like window placement, etc - I think)
- user (user project settings like breakpoints, etc - I think)

Also, don't put in any object files, executables, auto-generated files (like headers that might be generated).

in the end there is a file with name *.vssscc which you should not commit that duo to having sensitive data's.

good luck .